# Moving an item inside of a flex container to the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to move the register button from the middle to the right (as see on the following photos) Without it affecting the 3 items in the middle.

**So this is what I have:**
[image: present: CSS Menu Bar]

**This is what I'm trying to get:**
[image: Desired: CSS Menu Bar]

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #323642;
}

.menubar {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #272a33;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.menuitem {
  padding: 11px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 29px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Ostrich Sans";
  color: #ee5f95;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#login_button {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ee5f95;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Ostrich Sans";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 33px;
  transition: 0.7s;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#login_button:hover {
  width: 110px;
  background-color: #ae466d;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<head lang="Eng">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menubar" id="hey">
    <a class="menuitem" id="firstmenuitem" href="./buy_sell.html">Buy & Sell</a>
    <a class="menuitem" href="./exchange.html">Exchange</a>
    <a class="menuitem" href="./events.html">Events</a>
    <div id="delimeter"></div>
    <button id="login_button">Register</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have tried adding `margin-right:auto;` though it just completly shifter the button to the right and didn't leve any space between it and the window. I have also tried adding `justify-content: space-between;` but it didn't give me what I wanted. if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put the position of the button `absolute` like this :

```
#login_button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ee5f95;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Ostrich Sans";
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 33px;
    transition: 0.7s;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fh3cj02d/

Comment: This sort of worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flexbox inside a flexbox like this

```css
  body {
    background-color: #323642;
  }

  .menubar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;    
    background-color: #272a33;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .left {    
    flex: 1;    
  }

  .middle {    
    display: flex;        
  }
  
  .right {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;        
    align-items: center;
  }
  

  .menuitem {    
    padding: 11px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-left: 29px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Ostrich Sans";
    color: #ee5f95;
    text-decoration: none;
  }


  #login_button {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ee5f95;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Ostrich Sans";
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 33px;
    transition: 0.7s;    
  }

  #login_button:hover {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #ae466d;
    transition: 0.7s;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head lang="Eng">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menubar" id="hey">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle">
      <a class="menuitem" id="firstmenuitem" href="./buy_sell.html">Buy & Sell</a>
      <a class="menuitem" href="./exchange.html">Exchange</a>
      <a class="menuitem" href="./events.html">Events</a>
      <div id="delimeter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <button id="login_button">Register</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I like this because it's purely flexbox, no absolute positioning or margin auto. Also the `.middle` div is naturally centered this way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to make the left margin of the first and last item `auto`. In this example, you would apply a left margin to `.menuitem:last-of-type` and `#login_button`.

```css
body {
    background-color: #323642;
}

.menubar {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #272a33;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
.menuitem {
    padding: 11px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-left: 29px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Ostrich Sans";
    color: #ee5f95;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menuitem:first-of-type {
    margin-left: auto; /* NEW */
}
#login_button {
    margin-left: auto; /* NEW */
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ee5f95;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Ostrich Sans";
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 33px;
    transition: 0.7s;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#login_button:hover {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #ae466d;
    transition: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="menubar" id="hey">
        <a class="menuitem" id="firstmenuitem" href="./buy_sell.html">Buy & Sell</a>
        <a class="menuitem" href="./exchange.html">Exchange</a>
        <a class="menuitem" href="./events.html">Events</a>
        <div id="delimeter"></div>
        <button id="login_button">Register</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As noted, I have tried doing this the problem is that it "glues" the button to the browser window. (I want to have some space between both the browser window and the button)

Comment: @Fozoro you can just add some `padding-right` to the container, but absolutely positioning you login button (from another answer here) is better because you're changing its width on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just edit your body this way:

```
<body>
<div class="menubar" id="hey">
    <a class="menuitem" id="firstmenuitem" href="./buy_sell.html">Buy & Sell</a>
    <a class="menuitem" href="./exchange.html">Exchange</a>
    <a class="menuitem" href="./events.html">Events</a>
    <div id="delimeter"></div>
    <button class="festa" id="login_button">Register</button>
</div>
```

and add this css class:

```
.festa {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

This will keep the 3 buttons in the perfect center of the screen and the register one to the right, but they will overlap onto small screens.

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5xbnhkcr/

Otherwise you can play with flexbox weights (this is similar to your desired result)

modify body this way:

```
<body>
  <div class="menubar" id="hey">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="menuitem" id="firstmenuitem" href="./buy_sell.html">Buy & Sell</a>
    <a class="menuitem" href="./exchange.html">Exchange</a>
    <a class="menuitem" href="./events.html">Events</a>
  <div id="delimeter"></div>
  </div>
    <button class="festa" id="login_button">Register</button>
</div>
```

and add those css classes:

```
.buttons {
  flex: 9;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.festa {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Using **flex: 9;** and **flex: 1;** will divide the div into 10 parts.
The part containing the 3 buttons will occupy 9/10 of the width and the register button 1/10.

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5hp2v7L/